# Lower Bound (via testing) vs. Upper Bound (via proof) for Correctness

Tags: testing, types, theory

[Chris Smith's article](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2010-07-17-what-to-know-before-debating-type-systems) "What to know before debating type systems" contains the following unexplained statement:

> Testing: establishes upper bounds on correctness
>     Proof: establishes lower bounds on correctness

The context is comparing the benefits of proving program correctness (e.g. with a type-checker) vs. testing program behaviour (e.g. with TDD in a dynamically typed language).

What are the "upper" and "lower" bounds on correctness in this context?

Comment: A bit of a clue is further down, under Dynamic Typing Returns: "Recall that testing establishes only upper bounds on correctness. (Dijkstra said it best: 'Program testing can be used to show the presence of bugs, but never to show their absence.')" I'm still not sure why that's different than types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you have a program and you know basically nothing about how it works. It's supposed to have a bunch of properties (say, X, Y, and Z), but you're not really sure whether it does. What can you do to figure this out?

One option would be to try to use a program verification tool to formally prove that the program has properties X, Y, and Z. Unfortunately, in general, it's impossible to automatically verify that a program has any interesting properties (thanks, halting problem!), so even if the program actually has these properties, you may never be certain of this. However, if the program checker reports that the program does indeed have property X, you can say that *at the very least*, the program does X. In that sense, you're "lower-bounding" the correctness of the program: it definitely has property X, and possibly has some more properties.

Another option would be to run the program and see what happens. Suppose during testing you find a test case that causes the program to misbehave and, therefore, definitely not have property Z. Your test cases didn't expose any other errors, though. In that case, because you saw the program misbehave, you know for certain that it doesn't have property Z. Therefore, you've "upper-bounded" how correct the program is - it definitely doesn't have property Z, but you can't rule anything else out.

If you put the two of these together, you've got a proof that your program has property X and you have direct evidence that it doesn't have property Z. You don't know whether it has property Y or not, since that wasn't settled either way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't get it -- it sounds like you're comparing the case of "types check" to the case of "tests fail", and your definition of "lower-bounding" seems equivalent to "demonstrating correctnes" and "upper-bounding" to "demonstrating incorrectness." I'm sure that's not what you meant but would appreciate expanding why.

Comment: @nafg It's reasoning by analogy. One purpose of a type system is to catch errors before they occur in the program. A sound but incomplete type system that's too strict will prevent some safe programs from compiling (but guarantees a lack of type errors for anything that compiles), while an unsound but complete type system will let programs compile that shouldn't but always compiles programs that are correct. The analogy to testing is similar - compile-time checks lower-bound correctness by saying "you're at least this good," while running the program upper-bounds it by saying "you're wrong."

Comment: I still don't get it, compile-time checks can say you're wrong and running a test can say you're at least this good. Perhaps it would help to define what "range" we're bounding and what makes one end higher or lower and what's in the middle

Comment: @nafg Think of low as "little information about the program" and high as "lots of information about the program." A compiler that rejected everything would tell you basically nothing about the program, and progressively better and better type systems tell you progressively more about the program, so better type systems provide stronger lower bounds on the information about what the program does. A test case that doesn't check anything says "the program could basically do anything," and better and better test cases restrict what could happen. Better tests therefore upper-bound behaviors.